# How to limit AEM access to localhost?

Tags: java, security, networking, aem

To load some code, I need a clean local AEM Author instance running on my laptop. I start it using CLI like :

```
bash$ java -jar aem-author-p4502.jar -nointeractive
```

Default user/password is then admin/admin to access AEM on `http://localhost:4502`.  I'm ok with that but I've tested from another computer and port 4502 is open from full local network.

I'd like to limit access only from localhost, maybe by configuring listener address to `127.0.0.1` only. How ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recent AEM versions uses Apache Felix Lightweight HTTP Service as HTTP Server. I found how to bind it to `127.0.0.1` when it is embedded in AEM.

Configuration file is `crx-quickstart/launchpad/config/org/apache/felix/http.config`. I added last line :

```
:org.apache.felix.configadmin.revision:=L"1"
org.apache.felix.http.session.timeout=I"10"
org.apache.felix.https.jetty.protocols.excluded=[ \
  "SSLv3", \
  ]
org.apache.felix.proxy.load.balancer.connection.enable=B"true"
service.pid="org.apache.felix.http"
org.apache.felix.http.host="127.0.0.1"
```

Now AEM Author is available only from localhost.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to add an exception on your firewall to the port 4502 and only enable connections from your local and deny the others.

Regards,

Comment: Thanks, it would work but I'm looking for simpler solution.